# Network DISABLED and how to fix this

Tags: networking

I have Lenovo V14 iil and it shows this message

```
*-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:45:e2:33:f7:5b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8822ce driverversion=5.9.0-rc4+ firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:138 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:83000000-8300ffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

Any ideas how to fix it? I cannot connect with my WiFi.

Comment: Please  edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: This is the output

Comment: 0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
3: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: I think it's time for a full diagnostic report: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: Thank you for your time. My problem is solved. I upgraded my system from 18.04 that I had installed initially to 20.04. Now, the wifi network works perfectly. Some drivers may have been missed and they were downloaded when I upgrade the OS.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working by whatever means.